# traversing DOM from code-behind

Tags: asp.net, dom, traversal, code-behind

I have a asp.net webpage with a series of hidden input fields that I use in order to communicate values from client-side to code-behing at submit time.

```
<input type="hidden" id="zorro1" value="somevalue set at runtime from client-side" />
<input type="hidden" id="zorro2" value="somevalue set at runtime from client-side" />
.../... 
<input type="hidden" id="zorron" value="somevalue set at runtime from client-side" />
```

Now I need to extract these values from code-behind.
I can write this ugly thingy:

```
dim aValue as string = zorro1.value
dim aValue as string = zorro2.value
.../...
dim aValue as string = zorron.value
```

It works, but I would like to "findcontrol" each hidden input like this, with LINQ, in pseudo-code:

```
dim inputControls = from c in page.controls where id.startswith("zorro") select s

for each ic in inputControls
    aValue = ic.value
    aId = ic.ID
next
```

Can someone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer somewhere on the web, and it works:

Within the HTML page itself, you can add objects at your convenience, like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="someMeaningfulID" runat="server" value="some Value" />
```

From Javascript its easy to change the value of such objects.
In your code behind, add this sub:

```
    Private Sub AddControls(ByVal page As ControlCollection, ByVal controlList As ArrayList)
    For Each c As Control In page
        If c.ID IsNot Nothing Then
            controlList.Add(c)
        End If

        ' A pinch of recursivity never hurts :-)
        If c.HasControls() Then
            call AddControls(c.Controls, controlList)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And when you need it:

```
Dim controlList As New ArrayList()
Call AddControls(Page.Controls, controlList)

For Each c In controlList
        If c.id.startswith("something I'm looking for") Then ...

        If c.value <> "" Then....

        If c.someProperty = someValue tThen...
.../...
```